# Conda environment exported via conda-pack issue - No module named 'xxxx' error

Tags: python, conda

I used conda-pack to move environment to different server but it failed with this error

```
(jupyterhub_new2) xxxxx@yyyyyy: bin $ ./jupyterhub --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./jupyterhub", line 8, in <module>
    from jupyterhub.app import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyterhub'
```

I've created conda env on remote server (with internet access). I've installed python3.6 jupterhub and conda-pack.

```
conda install python=3.6.8
conda install -c conda-forge conda-pack
conda install jupyterhub=1.0.0=py36_0
conda install anaconda-clean=1.1.0=py36_1
conda install -c conda-forge dockerspawner=0.11.1 
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterhub-ldapauthenticator=1.2.2=py36_0
```

Jupyterhub is running so I pack the environment and moved it into test-server (without internet)

```
conda pack -n jupyterhub_new
```

I extracted environment and activated it.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/data/miniconda3/envs/jupyterhub_new
sudo tar -xzf jupyterhub_new.tar.gz -C /mnt/data/miniconda3/envs/jupyterhub_new
eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
conda activate jupyterhub_new
```

But in the end Jupyterhub in environment can't be even started

```
(jupyterhub_new2) xxxxx@yyyyyy: bin $ which conda
/mnt/data/miniconda3/bin/conda
(jupyterhub_new2) xxxxx@yyyyyy: bin $ which python
/mnt/data/miniconda3/envs/jupyterhub_new2/bin/python
(jupyterhub_new2) xxxxx@yyyyyy: bin $ conda -V
conda 4.7.12
(jupyterhub_new2) xxxxx@yyyyyy: bin $ jupyterhub -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/data/miniconda3/envs/jupyterhub_new2/bin/jupyterhub", line 8, in <module>
    from jupyterhub.app import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jupyterhub'
```

Conda on the is installed from the same file on the both servers.

test-server is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo), remote server is CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Any idea how to fixed this ? I've seen many errors in conda with "No module named XXXX" but I didn't find any solution not requiring internet access.

*edit 1: yes, jupyter is installed*

```
(jupyterhub_new2) xxxx@yyyy: ~ $ conda list -n jupyterhub_new2 jupyter 
# packages in environment at /mnt/data/miniconda3/envs/jupyterhub_new2: 
# 
# Name                       Version Build  Channel 
jupyterhub                   1.0.0   py36_0 
jupyterhub-ldapauthenticator 1.2.2   py36_0 conda-forge 
(jupyterhub_new2) xxxx@yyyyy: ~ $
```

Comment: yes it's installed (edited original question)